# How to split only "±" in a python string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

How to convert the "**±**" into "**+-**" or vice versa in a python string?

For example I have this string `18.1±0.3% hemolysis at 50µM` and only want to split `±` in this string `+-`.

Comment: `.replace("±", "+-")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not splitting. You call it so, because, graphically, it looks that way. But there is not other relation (other than appearance in your fonts) between '±' and '+' and '-'.

So what you are looking for, is just good, old, pattern search and replace.

```py
mystring.replace('±', '+-')
```